# Please explain : logβα logγβ = logγα log operation formula proof

Tags: logarithms

$ \log_\beta \alpha \log_\gamma \beta = \log_\gamma \alpha$

proof is given [here](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AF%B9%E6%95%B0#%E8%BF%90%E7%AE%97%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%8F) -in 链式 section

[proof from wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI8Eh.png)

I cannot find this formula's english name(it is not about derivative as its name suggests)nor any version with further explaination except this. I don't understand the first line of proof, please explain. Thanks.

Comment: Would you prefer an answer in English or Chinese?

Comment: Both are ok to me.

Comment: You need to understand two facts, (i) $\log_\gamma\beta=\frac{\ln\beta}{\ln\gamma}$ and (ii) when the proof rewrites the original logarithms using (i), it confusingly swaps the order. Do you know (i), and if so how to prove it? Proof of (i):$$e^{\ln\beta}=\beta=\gamma^{\log_\gamma\beta}=e^{\ln\gamma\times\log_\gamma\beta}\implies\ln\beta=\ln\gamma\times\log_\gamma\beta.$$

Comment: It's usually referred to in English as the Change of Base formula, and is usually written as $$log_ab=\frac{log_cb}{log_ca}$$ in school exam formula books.